# Do I need to replace my HDMI port? (ASUS Vivobook, "unsupported format" error with any screen / cable / OS / resolution / refresh rate)

Tags: laptop, display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have driven myself mad over this display-out issue for weeks.

HDMI output from my ASUS Vivobook 14 is no longer recognized on any screens, giving either "No source" or "Unsupported format" errors.
This issue suddenly started a few weeks back.

Additional information:

- The connected display **is** recognized by the computer, and the various display settings can be adjusted in the OS settings GUI, but to no avail.
- One display **DOES WORK** when the output resolution is set to 1024x768 (not its native resolution), but the screen looks pink and glitchy ([**VIDEO**](https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZyD5DmOF_14)).
- The error persists between OS's (Windows 10 and Endeavor OS)
- I am running the latest AMD drivers (Ryzen 5 3500U) on both OS's, and my BIOS is updated.
- I have tried many cables, all of which work with other devices.
- The HDMI port does not look damaged outwards, but I haven't yet opened the laptop.

Troubleshooting this stuff is awful due to the ungodly amount of noob-friendly guides for simple HDMI issues, but I've been on many, many forums trying to find someone with this exact issue.

My guess is I need to try to replace the HDMI port. But before I do - do you have any further ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the issue persists between OS's shows that this is definitely a hardware problem.  Although unlikely, try a different HDMI cable, to make sure that isnt the issue.  While it *could* be the port, it is not likely.  I have personally never seen a port go bad, unless it was physically damaged.  Use a magnifying glass and check the HDMI port itself for any dirt or debris lodged in it that could be blocking a pin, or for damaged pins.  Assuming they are good, its likely the GPU itself that is bad.  If it is under warranty, definitely have Asus look at it.  I have a strong feeling you will either need to replace the motherboard or get a new laptop.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I assumed as much myself. It's not under warranty, so I'll be opening it up and taking a look, I guess.